# Explicit homemorphism between code space

Tags: metric-spaces

Given a finite set we can construct the string (or code)space $S^\omega$ with the metric $\rho(w,w')=r^m$ where $w,w'\in S^\omega$ and $m$ is the maximum number such that the two strings $w,w'$ coincide. This is an ultrametric.

I want to know an explicit homeomorphism between $S_1^\omega$ and $S_2^\omega$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are different set with different finite cardinality.

It is known that they are homeomorphic because they both are Cantor sets.

Are these maps in some sense unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $S_1=\{0,1\}$ and $S_2=\{00,01,1\}$. There exists a canonical function $\phi:S_2^{\omega}\rightarrow S_1^{\omega}$ which i easily seen to be a homeomorphism. You can do this with every finite set.